# Correlation is a symmetric measure, but scatter plot matrix shows asymmetric dependence

Tags: time-series, correlation, random-variable, nonlinear, symmetry

The **correlation matrix** demonstrates that correlation is a **symmetric measure**: $\rho(X,Y) = \rho(Y,X)$ since the lower off-diagonals are mirror images of the upper off-diagonals.

The **scatterplot matrix** below similarly shows each pair of variables twice. For example, the stock returns for McDonalds vs Disney ($X$ vs $Y$) is the second plot in the first row.  The reverse, Disney vs McDonalds ($Y$ vs $X$) is the first plot in the second row.

[image]

Looking at just those two cells of the scatter plot matrix, we automatically can tell that they are not identical graphs. This contradicts what we see in a correlation matrix, instead implying that there is an **asymmetric dependence** between $X$ and $Y$: $\phi(X,Y) \neq \phi(Y,X)$, where $\phi$ is some stronger dependence measure that picks up total (linear and non-linear and asymmetric) dependence.

Does this invalidate the usage of correlation for real data that tend to have asymmetric relationships? Is **non-linear co-dependence** between $X$ and $Y$ causing, or is a factor behind, the asymmetry? What statistical tools can be used instead?

Comment: Correlation is *one number*, a plot is a collection of points, so clearly plots can differ in appearance in some ways without changing the correlation. ... How are you judging "correlation" when you look at those plots, to the extent that you believe you can assert that they have different correlation (i,e, "$\rho(X,Y) \neq \rho(Y,X)$")? Are you looking at the change of the angle to the horizontal of the major axis of the marked ellipses? (What happens to those when you standardize the variables and plot them on *identical* sets of axes?)

Comment: thanks for catching the typo, i've edited

Comment: I'm no less at a loss after your edit. What are you seeing that's asymmetric? Again, are you looking at the change of the angle to the horizontal of the major axis of the marked ellipses? (What happens to those when you standardize the variables and plot them on identical sets of axes?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing that, the plot with location $(i,j)$ is rotated 90 degrees to the left and then mirroed through the vertical axis w.r.t. the plot at location $(j,i)$. Thereby the $x_1$ axis of the first plot takes the place of the $x_2$ axis of the second plot and vice versa. So unless $\text{mean}(x_1)\approx \text{mean}(x_2)$ and $\text{Var}(x_1)\approx \text{Var}(x_2)$ the plot appearances are going to change.

But this does not mean that the correlation value is going to be different, because the linear dependence between the variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ remains the same.

As an example of the plot appearance remaining similar if both mean and variance are equal:
[image]

But as soon as we change the variance or mean of one of the variables:
[image]

**Conclusion**: It's common that scatterplot matrix doesn't give us symmetric plots. But this does not in any way mean that the correlation between variables have changed. We have only modified the axis positions.